# Bulk update matching column values in mysql every row

Tags: mysql

I have a table named `posts` and column `content`.

I want to change all values in the `content` column which contains **<a href** to **<a id="links" href**

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`REPLACE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function:

```
UPDATE posts 
SET content = REPLACE(content, '<a href', '<a id="links" href') 
WHERE content LIKE '%<a href%'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! succeeded

Comment: Yes, I will upvoting the answer in 3 minutes